# Перестал работать git в PhpStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm

Может быть кто-то знает в чем может быть причина, не могу понять из-за чего перестало работать.

**PhpStorm 2017.3.4 для OS X**

Git прекрасно работать в консоле, но в шторме всегда говорит "`Could not read remote repository.`"

Пробовал удалять шторм, руками удалял все возможные настройки из `~/Library/`, устанавливал все заново, но ничего не помогает. Одна и также ошибка. Это появилось после полной переустановки системы с нуля и восстановления некоторых данных из Time Machine.

Answer (score 3):

У меня подобное было, когда я случайно открыл проект с несколькими приложениями.
Каждое приложение имело свой гит репозиторий. Возможно вы сделали точно так же?

Если нет, то вы можете связаться с русскоязычной поддержкой джетбрэйнс по этому имейлу - sales@jetbrains.com и обсудить вашу проблему.